# How does the Pauli exclusion work on fermions but not on bosons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, pauli-exclusion-principle

How does fractional spin effect the symmetry of combined wavefunctions?

Why is Planck constant the universal anchor for determining if a particle is a Boson or a Fermion?

Answer (score 3):

The relation between spin and the exclusion principle is called the spin statistics theorem, but I don't think there is an elementary explanation for it (other than doing the math).

Plancks constant does not determine if a particle is a boson or a fermion

Comment: There is the elementary handwaving that exchanging two particles is half a rotation. At least in 3D, a full rotation gives the state that one started with, but in 2D one can have anyons (fractional quantum Hall effect).